# How to determine bridge IP of docker swarm container

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm trying to set up a framework, using `docker swarm`, where I can connect from an external system (via ssh or whatever) into a specific service's container. So, I'm able to do this using something like:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh ubuntu@10.0.0.18 nc 172.18.0.4 22" -l root foo
```

Here `10.0.0.18` is one of the swarm nodes and I then connect to the gateway bridge address (`172.18.0.4`) for that specific container.

In order to provide some automation around this I'd like to be able to `inspect` whatever docker object in order to map a containers' ID to its bridge IP. I'd like to create a mapping of something like:

```
{ 
  container_id: {
    swarm_node: <Swarm node IP>,
    bridge_ip:  <Container's bridge IP>
  }
}
```

However, I cannot see any kind of struct which shows the bridge info for a specific container. I can always `exec` into a given container and run `ifconfig` but I was hoping to avoid that.

Any pointers appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try starting with this:

```
docker service ls -q \
| xargs docker service ps -f desired-state=running -q \
| while read task_id; do 
  docker inspect -f '{{printf "%.12s" .Status.ContainerStatus.ContainerID }}:
  { swarm_node: {{.NodeID}},
    bridge_ip: {{range .NetworksAttachments}}{{if ne "ingress" .Network.Spec.Name }}{{.Addresses}}{{end}}{{end}}
  }' $task_id
done
```

You may need to cleanup the container IP a bit since it's coming out as a list of IP's in with a bit length included. And the swarm node is actually the node id, not the node IP. I also hardcoded the exclusion for "ingress", not sure if there's a cleaner way.

To map node ID's to IP addresses, here's another one to work with:

```
docker node ls -q \
| xargs docker node inspect -f '{ {{.ID}}: {{.Status.Addr}} }'
```

Comment: Thanks for that, however in my setup the `bridge_ip` is showing the _overlay_ IP. At least in a 'standard' setup I can't connect to this IP from a swarm node.

Comment: @JensD trying to use a local bridge network with a swarm service is only partially supported right now. You're probably better off using an attachable overlay network. See [this issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/27082) for more details. If you're getting a bridge IP address for your containers, I think you'll need to get that from the container on the node locally.

Comment: Changed your script little bit to make it work if there are more than one nodes in swarm cluster

   `for node in $(docker service ls -q); do 
      docker service ps -f desired-state=running -q $node \
      | while read task_id; do 
        docker inspect -f '{{printf "%.12s" 
    .Status.ContainerStatus.ContainerID }}:
       { swarm_node: {{.NodeID}},
          bridge_ip: {{range .NetworksAttachments}}{{if ne "ingress" 
    .Network.Spec.Name }}{{.Addresses}}{{end}}{{end}}
        }' $task_id
      done
    done`